# Why are regions excluded in my network map using cytoscape?

Tags: neural-network, correlation, cytoscape

I uploaded a correlation table for network analysis, but cytoscape is excluding certain regions for reasons that are unclear? I do not want to exclude any regions. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We would need a bit more information in order to help you here.  How are you importing your correlation table?  Can you be a bit more descriptive about regions that are getting excluded?  Cytoscape doesn't exclude data that you've imported unless you've specifically filtered it, or you have zoomed in, so it's not clear what might be going on.

-- scooter